# str to int: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, unit-testing, type-conversion

I am trying to write a unit test in Django/Python.
I have csv files I want to use to create records
but I get an error I do not understand when I try to convert a str to int:

**Error**

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'med_dru' (med_dru is an integer)

**Code**

```py
liste_correspondance = "adm_med.csv"
file1 = open(liste_correspondance,'r')
    reader = csv.reader(file1)
    for row in reader:
        Medicament.objects.create(med_dru = int(row[1]),med_sit = row[2],med_pay = row[5],med_num = row[6])
```

Comment: Can you debug the value of row[1] that's causing the error? Maybe is getting a empty value...

Comment: It's not an empty value, it's the string "med_dru".  Looks like you are trying to convert the header row.

Comment: This error means you try to convert to an int something that cannot be converted to an int. For example : int('a') will return the same error as yours, because 'a' cannot be converted to int.

It happens at your code last line : `med_dru = int(row[1])`
Try to print `row[1]`, because apparently you cannot convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create an object for the header row.  Try just throwing away the first line:

```py
liste_correspondance = "adm_med.csv"
file1 = open(liste_correspondance,'r')
    reader = csv.reader(file1)
    next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:
        Medicament.objects.create(med_dru = int(row[1]),med_sit = row[2],med_pay = row[5],med_num = row[6])
```

Comment: thanks, I realized like you say taht I was trying to convert the header...

Comment: Happy to help.  Do you mind accepting the answer?  Thanks!